# Exposure Fusion returns blue image with OpenCV on Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, hdr

I'm trying to implement Exposure Fusion with OpenCV 3.0.0 on Android using MergeMertens class.
The problem is that image is returned in blue. Here is the screenshot of how it looks like: http://take.ms/agYSD

I suppose the problem is with RGB/BGR representation of files. I tried to convert from RGB to BGR and vice versa before and after applying merger, anyway got the problem with color.

If I'm using grayscaled image then everything is allright.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
    public void process(String[] InFiles, float[] InTimes, String OutImage) {
        List<Mat> images = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + _App.getPackageName() + "/";
        Mat hdrImage = new Mat();
        Mat ldrImage = new Mat();

        Mat times = new MatOfFloat(InTimes);

        for(int i = 0; i < InFiles.length; i++) {
            Mat m = Imgcodecs.imread(path + InFiles[i]);
            images.add(m);
        }


        Photo.createMergeMertens().process(images,  hdrImage);
        Core.multiply(hdrImage, new Scalar(255.0), ldrImage);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(path + OutImage, ldrImage);
}
```

Comment: can you try: `Core.multiply(hdrImage, new Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0), ldrImage);` ?

Comment: Miki,  thx! That was the problem!